# Best Way to load data from Server on View Pager in ONE GO

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-progressbar

I have a View Pager with 5 pages which will show the 5 different data on 5 View Pages. I want that it should load the data for all the pages in one go.

**Requirement**: When user opens the View Pager screen for the first time, then it should load all the 5 pages i.e when user swipes for next page it should show the data of the other page without Loading.

I have implemented the same, with progress bar at every View Pager PAGE. i.e when user swipes, the progress dialog comes to fetch the data from server and show.

Let me know if anybody has best or optimized to achieve my requirement.

My Example Pager

```
 public class BookMagListViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
        private FragmentManager fragmentManager ;
        private int[] bookMagListOptionArray;

        public BookMagListViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int[] bookMagListArray) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragmentManager = fm;
            this.bookMagListOptionArray = bookMagListArray;
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
            Fragment fragment = null;

            switch (arg0) {
            case BookMagListFragment.OFFERS:
                fragment = new BookMagOfferListFragment();
                loadDATA(OFFERS);

                break;
            case BookMagListFragment.ALL_CAT:
                fragment = new BookMagAllCatListFragment();
                loadDATA(ALL_CAT);

                break;
            case BookMagListFragment.BEST_SELLER:
                fragment = new BookMagBestSellerListFragment();
                loadDATA(BEST_SELLER);

                break;
            case BookMagListFragment.REGIONAL:
                fragment = new BookMagRegionalListFragment();
                loadDATA(REGIONAL);

                break;
            case BookMagListFragment.FREE:
                fragment = new BookMagFreeListFragment();
                loadDATA(FREE);

                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return this.bookMagListOptionArray.length;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't a lot of page. So, you can create the views of all of your fragments when viewpager creating. And you should loading data inside of fragment's `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()`.

```
  mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
```

check this method at [developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))